# birt won't save data set, "the structure is invalid" error

Tags: java, eclipse, birt

We're trying to update a BIRT report project after recreating a database. So I type the new query but when I move to the Parameters tab (or any tab), the error:

`The structure is floating, and its handler is invalid!`

pops up, and in the error log the following error is shown:

`Problems occurred when invoking code from plug-in: "org.eclipse.jface".`

Then after that nothing else works; the changes don't register (there's no asterisk near the library name in the tab), and I can't save anything.

Stack trace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: The structure is floating, and its handle is invalid!
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.MemberHandle.<init>(MemberHandle.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DataSetParameterHandle.getMember(DataSetParameterHandle.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.StructureHandle.getProperty(StructureHandle.java:187)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.api.DataSetParameterHandle.getPosition(DataSetParameterHandle.java:184)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.adapter.oda.impl.DataSetParameterAdapter.getPositions(DataSetParameterAdapter.java:1431)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.adapter.oda.impl.DataSetParameterAdapter.getDriverDefinedParameters(DataSetParameterAdapter.java:1384)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.adapter.oda.impl.DataSetAdapter.updateDesignerValue(DataSetAdapter.java:982)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.adapter.oda.impl.DataSetAdapter.updateDataSetHandle(DataSetAdapter.java:929)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.adapter.oda.impl.DataSetAdapter.updateDataSetHandle(DataSetAdapter.java:410)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.adapter.oda.impl.ModelOdaAdapter.updateDataSetHandle(ModelOdaAdapter.java:188)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.model.adapter.oda.ModelOdaAdapter.updateDataSetHandle(ModelOdaAdapter.java:203)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.util.DTPUtil.updateDataSetHandle(DTPUtil.java:207)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.PropertyPageWrapper.canLeave(PropertyPageWrapper.java:132)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog.showPage(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:568)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog.showSelectionPage(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:482)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetEditor.showSelectionPage(DataSetEditor.java:913)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog$2$1.run(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:438)
    at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.property.AbstractPropertyDialog$2.selectionChanged(AbstractPropertyDialog.java:433)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer$2.run(Viewer.java:164)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.Viewer.fireSelectionChanged(Viewer.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.updateSelection(StructuredViewer.java:2188)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleSelect(StructuredViewer.java:1211)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1241)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$4(OpenStrategy.java:233)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:403)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.runEventLoop(Window.java:826)
    at org.eclipse.jface.window.Window.open(Window.java:802)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.ui.dialogs.BaseDialog.open(BaseDialog.java:111)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.providers.EditableDataSetNodeProvider.performEdit(EditableDataSetNodeProvider.java:102)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.DefaultNodeProvider.performRequest(DefaultNodeProvider.java:472)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.actions.EditAction.doAction(EditAction.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.actions.AbstractElementAction.run(AbstractElementAction.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.internal.ui.views.RenameListener.doubleClick(RenameListener.java:214)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$1.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireDoubleClick(StructuredViewer.java:843)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.AbstractTreeViewer.handleDoubleSelect(AbstractTreeViewer.java:1477)
    at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$4.widgetDefaultSelected(StructuredViewer.java:1246)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireDefaultSelectionEvent(OpenStrategy.java:249)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$0(OpenStrategy.java:246)
    at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:307)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1057)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4170)
    at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3759)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine$9.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:1113)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.swt.PartRenderingEngine.run(PartRenderingEngine.java:997)
    at org.eclipse.e4.ui.internal.workbench.E4Workbench.createAndRunUI(E4Workbench.java:138)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$5.run(Workbench.java:610)
    at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:567)
    at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:150)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:124)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:354)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:181)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:636)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:591)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1450)
```

I don't know what to search; all results I've come upon come from different errors. Starting with "-clean" doesn't work, recreating the BIRT report project doesn't work... Any nudge in the right direction would be help enough.

Regards, 
Cez

Comment: Because a BIRT report is actually XML in the back ground, the drag and drop interface does not always do exactly what you would expect.  Are you able to recreate this issue by building the report from scratch using the new data base as the source?

Comment: If I start from zero, the error doesn't appear at all. The old forms were probably corrupted, I don't know. This is my first time with BIRT and I'm still trying to get a feel for it.

Comment: Glad to hear you are up and running again.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error, but performing below steps helped me out.(I am working on a table )

1. Delete the data sets
2. Select the table, under property editor tab, click on binding tab, check Data set and select none.
3. You should get a prompt asking if you wish to clear all existing data feild information, Click on 'yes'.

All the data bindings with references to the deleted data sets will now be cleared and voila... continue with your work. Let me know if this worked for you too.